# Противоречит ли использование одной и той же функции принципу SOLID - DRY?

Tags: java

Я создал функцию печати элементов в списке, чтобы не прописывать один и тот же текст несколько раз (как говорится - don't repeat yourself). Но когда я уже провернул свою идею, задался вопросом - не сделал ли я то, чего хотел избежать, когда использовал свою функцию 5 раз подряд?

```
    printFeeding(animals.get(1), feedingSchedule.get(0));
    printFeeding(animals.get(4), feedingSchedule.get(1));
    printFeeding(animals.get(0), feedingSchedule.get(2));
    printFeeding(animals.get(2), feedingSchedule.get(3));
    printFeeding(animals.get(3), feedingSchedule.get(4));
}

public static void printFeeding(String animal, String feedingSchedule) {
    System.out.println("В " + feedingSchedule + " - " + animal);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама функция DRY не нарушает. Вот код который её вызывает - другое дело. Каждая строка делает три однотипных вызова методов. Их надо или спрятать в функцию более высокого уровня, или поместить в цикл.

Вызывайте функцию в цикле по массиву значений `{1, 4, 0, 2, 3}`:

```
    int animal_indices[] = {1, 4, 0, 2, 3};
    for (int i = 0; i < animal_indices.length; ++i) {
        // printFeeding(animals.get(animal_indices[i]), feedingSchedule.get(i));
        System.out.println("В " + feedingSchedule.get(i) + " - " + animals.get(animal_indices[i]));
    }
```

Функция `printFeeding` не нужна.